# Installing Chrome Frame on IE8

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-frame

Trying to install Chrome Frame on WindowsXP SP3, IE8, using the following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>

  $('#chrome1').on('click',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      CFInstall.check({
        mode: "overlay",
        url: "http://www.google.com/chromeframe/eula.html?user=true",
        destination: "www.mysite.com"
    });
  });
```

Mid way through the install I get "This content cannot be displayed in a frame". Since this Google's recommended install approach (http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started), I'm wondering why I get this?

Comment: Why does Google offer an overlay/inline mode if the iframe content fails in IE8?

Comment: 1) Are you sure the URL you are using resolves correctly? (Is it valid? Does a page show when you put it in your address bar?) 2) Does the page contain valid HTML? 3) Is the content an HTML page or something else?

Comment: The process of install is that when a user click the install button, it triggers Google's own function CFIinstall which opens Google's own url 'http://www.google.com/chromeframe/eula.html?user=true'. This works in that the mentioned url opens.  On that page, the user clicks a button to start the install and it's midway through this process that the error appears. So yes to all three questions for the parts that I can control.